# Sending the model back to the controller on form submission

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to create list using dropdown.
I have model class with following properties.

```
public class EditPaymentMethod
    {
        public List<string> BPay { get; set; }
        public List<BillerCode> BillerCodes { get; set; }
    }
public class BillerCode
{
    public List<string> CodeList { get; set; }
}
```

In my mock class, I'm creating mock data as follows:

```
public static EditPaymentMethod GetPaymentMethodDetails(int tenantID)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.MyProperty.BPay.Count; i++)
      {
        obj.BillerCodes.Add(new BillerCode { CodeList = new List<string> { "AAA" + i, "BBB" + i } });
      }

     return obj;
}
```

In View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditPaymentMethod","PaymentMethod",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.MyProperty.BPay.Count; i++)
    {
    <div class="list_scbill">
         @Html.Label("Biller Codes")
    </div>
    <div style="display: block; margin-left: 87px;">
         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BillerCodes[i].CodeList, new SelectList(Model.BillerCodes[i].CodeList))
    </div>
    }
    <div id="BtnsDiv">
        <button id="btn_SaveChanges" type="submit">
           Save
        </button>
        <button id="btn_Cancel" type="button">
           Cancel
        </button>
    </div>
}
```

In Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditPaymentMethod(EditPaymentMethod model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //CODE TO SAVE DATA THROUGH THE SERVICE  
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

When I try to submit the form, EditPaymentMethod gets the model with BillerCodes as null.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things right off the bat, number one you are not actually passing the model to your controller in the route values dictionary.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditPaymentMethod","PaymentMethod",new {model = Model}, FormMethod.Post))
```

will add your model as a parameter to your post.  Also your controller is currently a get request you will need to flag it as a post or the controller will by default try to get the serialized string from the url rather than the request body.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditPaymentMethod(EditPaymentMethod model)
```

Comment: Actually controller is getting model.<br> I'm making use of dropdown, so until I select a value the BillerCodes is getting null.<br> I have control which dynamically add code to the BillerCodes. When I submit the form the BIllerCodes list will be send to controller, I dont want to make selection of the codes in the list.

Comment: This is completely wrong. If the model contained value types, at best it would create a `RouteValueDictionary` containing the initial values of the model (not edited values), but since the model contains properties which are collections, the route values would look something like `BPay="System.Collections.Generic[string]"` and nothing would be bound to the model on post back.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListBoxFor` for a multi-select, instead of `DropDownListFor`, which just produces a single-select whose posted value will not be correct for the modelbinder to bind to a list.

Comment: I have text box where user enters biller code and button on its click the code is added to the list. I don't want user to select code from the list, its when the form is submitted the codes are returned in the model.

Answer (score 0):

For the same you have to create List Variable in Model
and on view page you have to

```html
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedList, new SelectList(Model.SelectList, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "js-example-basic-multiple form-control", @multiple = "multiple", @id = "SelectListId" })
```

```js
var ListModel = {
                    "Id": 0,
                    "SelectedList": $("#SelectedListId").val(),
                };
$.ajax({
                     url: '/Test/Test/',
                     type: "Post",
                     async: false,
                     dataType: "html",
                     data: JSON.stringify(ListModel),
                     contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                     success: function (result) {
                        
                     }
                 });
```

Model Should be :

```css
public class EditPaymentMethod
    {
        public List<string> BPay { get; set; }
        public List<BillerCode> BillerCodes { get; set; }
        public int[] SelectedList{ get; set; }
        
    }
```